# Unable to PUT big file (2gb) to aws s3 bucket (nodejs) | RangeError: data is too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I scouted trough all of the internet and everybody gives out different advice but none of them helped me.

Im currently trying to simply send file.buffer that gets send to my endpoint directly to aws bucket.

im using `PutObjectCommand` have correctly entered all the details in but there's apparently problem with me using simple `await s3.send(command)` because my 2.2gbs video is way too big.

i get this error when attempting to upload said file to cloud.

`RangeError: data is too long     at Hash.update (node:internal/crypto/hash:113:22)     at Hash.update (C:\Users\misop\Desktop\sebi\sebi-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\hash-node\dist-cjs\index.js:12:19)     at getPayloadHash (C:\Users\misop\Desktop\sebi\sebi-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist-cjs\getPayloadHash.js:18:18)     at SignatureV4.signRequest (C:\Users\misop\Desktop\sebi\sebi-auth\node_modules\@aws-sdk\signature-v4\dist-cjs\SignatureV4.js:96:71)     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE',   '$metadata': { attempts: 1, totalRetryDelay: 0 } }`

I browsed quite a lot,there's lots of people saying that i should be using `presigned url`,i did try however if i do `await getSignedUrl(s3,putCommand,{expires:3600});` then i do get generated url but there's not PUT send to cloud. when i read little more into it getSignedUrl is just for generating signed url therefore there's no way for me to use Put command there so im not sure how to approach this situation.
Im currently working with :

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.238.0",
"@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.238.0",
```

[image]

Honestly i've been testing lots of different ways i saw online but i wasnt successful following even amazon's official documentation where they mention these thing and i trully dont want to implement multipart upload for smaller than 4 ~ 5gbs of videos.

I'll be honored to hear any advice on this topic, thank you.

Get advice on how to implement simple video upload to aws s3 because of my many failed attempts on doing so since there's lots of information and vast majority doesnt work.

Comment: Multipart upload?

Comment: Im aware of multipart upload where you separate file into smaller chunk,but is it neccessary for files like mine thats about 2gbs big?

Comment: Is this a one-off activity? If so, you could try the AWS CLI, like `aws s3 cp local-file.avi s3://your-bucket/`.

Comment: You can do multipart uploads to signed urls - so your options are really 1 or 3 (and option 1 will suck). You basically always want to break up large files into chunks for transit in the real world - it will be a lot less painful.

Comment: A simple upload of a 2GB file from my local file system (streamed using fs.createReadStream) to S3 using the AWS SDK v3 works fine for me. Can you share more about the code you're running?

Comment: const awsUploadVideoCommand = new PutObjectCommand({
          Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
          Key: file.originalname,
          Body: file.buffer,
          ContentType: file.mimetype,
        });
        await s3.send(awsUploadVideoCommand);
        const signedVideoURL = await getSignedUrl(s3, awsUploadVideoCommand, {
          expiresIn: 3600,
        });

Comment: @lxg no it isnt,its for my client,im making video uploader so that he can later on simply upload his courses in the app aswell as to specify episode titles / sub-episode descriptions and all that,so i need it to simply take file.buffer that it gets from multer and send it to s3 for storage

Comment: @jarmod would it be possible that "data is too long" error im getting is due to me sending file buffer to s3 ? because im able to send any file around 30 mbs but then when it gets bigger im no longer able to

Comment: I modified my test to use fs.readFileSync so that it first reads the entire file into a buffer in RAM then uploads to S3 from that buffer. It worked fine for 1GB but failed at 2GB with ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE, but that's an `fs` limitation afaik, not the AWS SDK. I don't work with multer but are you able to stream the data from multer? Alternatively, do you have the option to provide your client with a pre-signed S3 URL that it can upload directly to S3, thus avoiding you proxying the entire 2GB upload in your back-end?

Comment: i was doing getSignedURL with PutObjectCommand option however it returned signed URL but the file didnt get uploaded to s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution to my problem was essentially using multer's s3 "addon" that had s3 property and had pre-done solution.**
`"multer-s3": "^3.0.1"` version worked even with file that have 5gbs and such. solutions such as using PutObject command inside presigned url method or presigned-post methods were unable to work with multer's `file.buffer` that node server receives after its being submitted.

If you experienced same problem and want quick and easy solution. use this [Multer-s3 npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3)

Comment: I hit this limit today. I upload large files locally which are then split in the bucket and stream-read into a database. This looks like a nice quick fix, but relying on packages to work around problems can be a trap. It's concerning that the last publish to that package was 2 years ago. Will the author keep up if something breaks or changes on the AWS side? IMO, streams are a better option.

Comment: Hey,compeletely agree with you,now that i understand better,i'd just implement "file-chunking" and upload separate parts  invidually lets say like 1gb per chunk